# Replace outliers with neighbour-Value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a plot with some outliers (wrong measurements):

[image]

The base data is good though. I want to just delete everything that is too far off the "current average". I tried using `pd.rolling().mean()` but with no satisfactory result:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.genfromtxt('shard_height_plot.csv', delimiter = ',')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index(0, inplace = True)
df2 = df.rolling(20).mean()

plt.plot(df)
plt.plot(df2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I tried to search the web for a good solution but couldn't find one. It shouldn't be that hard to delete data points, that jump through the roof, should it?

Edit:
data file can be downloaded here: https://ufile.io/pviuc

Edit2:

I takled this problem of too many outliers by improving my data set creation.

The core of it:

```
if abs(D - D_List[-2]) > 30:
            D = D_List[-2]
            D_List.pop()
            D_List.append(D)
```

Basically what this does is checking if the change of a value is larger than 30, if so it deletes the last value and replaces is with the second last. Not very spectacular but just what I need. I used one of the answers though because it is so much prettier. Thank you guys very much.

[image]

Comment: What defines a point as being "too far off the current average"?

Comment: Do you have the data available for download?

Comment: The rolling mean isn't what you want. The mean is going to be biased by your outliers, and as you can see from your plot, the window size can shift the location of features like peaks. You want more of a filter to your data. A median filter seems like it might work well.

Comment: I added a download link with the data set. Too far off could mean a difference to the last value in the data set of greater than 10.

Comment: I agree that a median filter would be better. You can also try a low pass filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try using [scipy.signal see docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html#scipy-signal-filtfilt):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import signal

data = np.genfromtxt('shard_height_plot.csv', delimiter = ',')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index(0, inplace = True)
df2 = df.rolling(20).mean()

b, a = signal.butter(3, 0.05)
y = signal.filtfilt(b,a, df[1].values)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(y, index=df2.index)


plt.plot(df, alpha=.3)
plt.plot(df2, alpha=.3)
plt.plot(df3)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Use medfilt:

```
y = signal.medfilt(df[1].values)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it not be possible to completely disregard the outliers? The correct data is warped this way.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov You'll have to play with the scipy signal library a little bit or understand filter theory to get exactly what you are looking for.  For example, that lower reading at about -40 or so, is that a real value or noise?  Do you want all those values between -45 and -30 to be dropped?  Sorry, you've reached my limits.

Comment: Out of curiousity would the downvoter care to explain?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution as well, I will study more closely these scipy.signal functions !

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to smooth a curve (rolling mean, GAM, smoothing spline etc.), my favorite one is the [Savitzky–Golay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter) method.
It works as follows: after having regressed a small window around a data point `y` onto a polynomial (with least squares), it uses this polynomial to get the estimation of your data point `^y`. Then the window is shifted forward by one data point.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

x = np.linspace(0,5,150)
y = np.cos(x) + np.random.random(150) * 0.15
yhat = savgol_filter(y, 49, 3)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x,yhat, color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that rolling mean can't work in your case with a perimeter as low as 20, since the outlier point will have a non-negligible weight (5%) and will always induce a big bias...

Comment: Thanks for sharing... I'll look at savgol more closely.  +1